# jQuery selector for element not on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery on the page:

```
$('#nav-icon1,#nav-icon3').click(function(){
});
```

And corresponding HTML like this:

```
<div id="nav-icon3" class="">
    <span class="whitehamburger origin"></span>
    <span class="whitehamburger origin"></span>
    <span class="whitehamburger origin"></span>
    <span class="whitehamburger origin"></span>
</div>
```

There's no `nav-icon1` anywhere on the page, but when I change the jQuery to be this:

```
$('#nav-icon3').click(function(){
});
```

It stops working.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Check the console for errors. Given your provided code, what you have should (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/ed9xsh62/) work.

Comment: Update: just realized a potential cause. I have two <div id="nav-icon3"> elements on the page. The code I have somehow matches both? Whereas the second code only matches the first one (which is actually hidden on the page) so it doesn't work. Why does $('#nav-icon1,#nav-icon3') match both nav-icon3 elements?

Answer (score 0):

it's necessary attach that event to your div? check if your spans are position "relative" because if they are "absolute" your div "nav-icon3" may not be visible with height:0px.

another way to add events is using "bind"

```
$(function(){
    $("#nav-icon3").bind('click', function()
{
// some code...
});
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
    $("#nav-icon3").bind('click', _onNavClick);
});

function _onNavClick(event)
{
// some code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems different error, what you are doing is working just how it is. Check it here jsfiddle.net/ed9xsh62/  Check your console or share URL to check the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function(){
      $( "#nav-icon3" ).click(function() {
         //code goes here
         //can do a simple alert to test the function
      });
    });
```

Could be a  possibility that you just did not have your code in document.ready function (I used the shorthand version). I tried your code and it worked perfectly as long as it was in the document.ready function.